# the local variable marker _$tag is never read

Tags: php, javascript

I'm beginner in php and javascript. I'm try to load data from mysql data base to create a dynamic markers. I'm getting a warning in eclipse that shows the local variable marker `_$tag` is never read.

Here is the line that contains warning :

```
var marker_<?php echo ($marker['NUM']);?> 
   = new google.maps.Marker({position: myLatlng, map: map, 
   title: <?php echo $marker['NOM']; ?>, icon: image});
```

`

Because I want to create marker name var like marker_id.

Comment: {{ $marker['NUM'] }} PRINTS $tag! checkout why it do that.

Comment: hello thk but how i do that plz i m big beginner

Comment: Look at echo $marker['NUM']; alone and see what is its print. Another thing, What's happening when you actually run your code! The Eclipse message is just an IDE message.

Comment: I explain what I do ,i create a php code with javascript that create dynamic marker_$marker['NUM'] using mysql data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may give you a lead.

```
<?php $_marker = "marker_".$marker['NUM'];?>
var <?php echo $_marker;?> 
   = new google.maps.Marker({position: myLatlng, map: map, 
   title: <?php echo $marker['NOM']; ?>, icon: image});
```

Comment: thks for the solution